# Selenium testing. Simple exception if there's an error on screen

Tags: c#, selenium

I need my test to fail if there's an error popup on the screen after performing Print operation.

Currently, this code is working:

```
  [TestMethod]
    [Description("Should Print")]
    public void PrintDetails()
    {
        mainPage.PrintDetails(driver);
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        Wait.WaitForNoErrorMsg(driver);
    }
```

--

```
public static void WaitForNoErrorMsg(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            string errorMsg = "//div[@class='errorMessage']";
            try
            {
                WaitForElementNotVisible(driver, errorMsg, 3);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

--

```
 public static void WaitForElementNotVisible(IWebDriver driver, string locator, int seconds)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(locator)));
    }
```

I feel that's not an optimal way and it could be done better using ExpectedException. Am I right?
Could you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by making the following changes:

```
[TestMethod]
[Description("Should Print")]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ApplicationException))]
public void PrintDetails()
```

And:

```
public static void WaitForNoErrorMsg(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            string errorMsg = "//div[@class='errorMessage']";
            try
            {
                WaitForElementNotVisible(driver, errorMsg, 3);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException();
            }
        }
```

What this will do is your test will expect an exception to be thrown and will only pass when the expected exception is thrown.

I wouldn't do this. Instead I would create two tests, one which tests the correct path and a second test that checks a bad scenario.

In both tests I would also skip on using exceptions altogether as they aren't needed and you can make things simpler by not using them.

I would change `WaitForNoErrorMsg` to `VerifyNoErrorMsg` and have it return a boolean:

```
public static bool WaitForNoErrorMsg(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            string errorMsg = "//div[@class='errorMessage']";
            try
            {
                WaitForElementNotVisible(driver, errorMsg, 3);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

And have your tests like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[Description("Should Print")]
public void PrintDetailsSuccess()
{
    mainPage.PrintDetails(driver);
    Thread.Sleep(300);
    bool errorMessagePresent = WaitForNoErrorMsg(driver);
    Assert.IsFalse(errorMessagePresent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solution is working. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess, "errorMessagePresent" should be renamed to "errorMessageAbsent", as we wait (verifying) that there will be no error. And the last line of code should be like Assert.IsTrue(errorMessageAbsent);

Comment: @NikolayM well it depends if you want to test to check that the error is present or it is absent. I would do both tests. In the first feed good input and verify the absence of the error message and in the second feed bad input and verify the presence of the error message.